# SQLAlchemy - adding OR condition with different filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For the SQL statement, I want to do an OR filter only if the input variable is not None.

E.g

```
# input variable
var_1 = "apple"
var_2 = "pear"

query = session.query(Table)
if var_1:
    query = query.filter(or_(Table.field1 == var_1))
if var_2:
    query = query.filter(or_(Table.field2 == var_2))
```

But this is not possible.  The 2nd query became an AND statement instead.

I don't want to do this because I don't want to compare an input variable if it's null or empty string.

```
query = query.filter(or_(Table.field1 == var_1, Table.field2 == var_2))
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can dynamically construct the "OR" part:

```
query = session.query(Table)

conditions = []
if abc:
    conditions.append(Table.field1 == abc)
if def:
    conditions.append(Table.field2 == def)

query = query.filter(or_(*conditions))
```

Also note that the `def` is a reserved word in Python, consider renaming this variable.

Comment: Ah nice, pretty convenient that `or_` can handle a single filter element properly

Comment: Use `or_(False, *conditions)` if you might have zero conditions. Since sqlalchemy 1.4 `or_` must have at least one parameter as it says [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_)

Comment: Nice, but can I  write the code  `Table.field1 ` by  using  reflection? like `Table['field']`